# Sympathic or Apolgetic Words or Phrases

Tags: word-usage

What words (english or foreign) which mean; There is something I need to tell you?

Comment: I understand "There is something I need to tell you" but I don't understand the question. What do you want to know?

Comment: The only thing I can think of that means anything like that is "We regret to inform you", which is traditionally how rejection letters to would-be authors begin, or how the military begins a letter to a soldier's family to let them know he's been killed.

Comment: What do you mean by "(English or foreign)"? Are you even asking about an English phrase?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got you right that you're looking for some expressions or idioms used to ***give bad news*** in a way that you show you're sorry, too at least as far as courtesy or civility is concerned.

> I regret to inform you that ...
>
> Unfortunately, ...
>
> I'm sorry to say (that) ...
>
> I'm sorry to tell you (that) ...
>
> I have some bad news for you (I'm afraid).
>
> I am sorry to have to inform you that ...
>
> Brace yourself (Which means *to ​prepare yourself ​physically or ​mentally for something ​unpleasant*).
>
> It is my unfortunate duty to report to you that ...
>
> There's no easy/nice way to say this, ...